# need to start reading messenger RNA since the letters AUG in DNA transcription

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this RNA messenger:

```
'UAUGCUAAUUCGAUAACCGA'
```

I want to make a function that starts storing from the `'AUG'`codon but I have no clue how to make this.
The result should look like this:

```
'AUGCUAAUUCGAUAACCGA'
```

I have already tried with this:

```
 cadenaseparada = []
 for i in range(0,fin,3):
     codon = v[i] +v[i+1] + v[i+2]
     cadenaseparada.append(codon)
```

Comment: the input is a string with no whitespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things are wrong there:

- You can't iterate over the whole string because you also include the two elements coming after the index.
- Also you shouldn't use a step size of 3 in case the `AUG` doesn't start at an index of `n * 3` (where `n` is any integer) you would miss it.
- You don't need to append you can exclude ranges of strings using the `[start:stop]` syntax.

A working example could be:

```
rna = 'U A U G C U A A U U C G A U A A C C G A'
rna = ''.join(rna.split()) # This just converts it to a string with no whitspaces.

# Don't iterate over the whole string, stop when reaching len(rna)-2
for i in range(0,len(rna)-2):
    # Break and only keep everything from here on
    # Compare the current 3 letters
    if rna[i:i+3] == 'AUG':
        out = rna[i:]
        break # End the loop here
print out
# 'AUGCUAAUUCGAUAACCGA'
```

Comment: Thanks its working, can you explain me the part where you compare the rna whith the 'AUG' please?

Comment: The `[i:i+3]` and `[i:]` are just slicing. The first means show the 3 letters starting by index (letter) `i` and the second one means all letters starting from `i` until the end. And the `break` is because the loop has found a solution and doesn't need to check the rest of the string.

Comment: @Jlasa - You are welcome. If you find this solution too slow then take a look at the other answer. Using `.find()` will also work. My answer is more oriented on improving your attempt than providing the most efficient answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
rna = 'UAUGCUAAUUCGAUAACCGA'
index = rna.find('AUG')
out = rna[index:] if index >= 0 else ''

print out
```

Comment: nice solution but you need to catch the case when there is no `'AUG'` in the string (?) Otherwise you return the [last letter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find). :)

Comment: This is, IMO, a better solution than the accepted answer because it implements the search using code that runs at C speed (rather than at Python speed). DNA is generally "big" data, and you will probably benefit from the speedup you get.

Comment: now you have an edge case when it already starts at index `0`. You could use `>=` instead of `>`. :-)

Comment: Input was from original version of question, now edited.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `index`?

```
dna = 'UAUGCUAAUUCGAUAACCGA'

try:
    mrna_index = dna.index('AUG')
except ValueError:
    mrna_index = None
    cadena_separada = None
else:
    cadena_separada = dna[mrna_index:]
```